# How to convert EBCDIC file to ASCII file using eighter UNIX or Informatica Power Center?

Tags: unix, informatica

Can you please let me know the approach to convert ebcdic file to ascii file using unix or informatica?

I have searched in google but no clue and expert says it can be done through power exchange but not sure about it.

Below is the sample file for your reference and few files may come in fixed width and few may come in delimited format since we have  multiple source applications which generates files.

Thanks in advance for your help and form past several days i have searched in google.

Answer (score 4):

You can use command like:

```
iconv -f EBCDIC -t ASCII filename >output_filename
```

or with `dd`

```
dd conv=ascii if=filename of=output_filename
```

Comment: do we have any approach through informatica power center?

Comment: you can use command task in informatica. put the commands in an .sh file then run it using informatica using the command task in workflow

Comment: i have tried with iconv and dd but no help. Iconv -f EBCDICUS -t ASCII file name is not supported and througing below message "iconv: illegal input sequence at position 321" and for dd it is giving some weired characters.

Comment: @user2471320, in such case it seems like your file have problem with encoding.